# How to get central time like yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss in javascript only

Tags: javascript, date

I'm aware of packages like moment.js, but I would like to use only javascript. How can I get the current time as a string in Central US time?

I tried

```
let s = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "America/Chicago" });
```

But this returns the format as `mm/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss` which I detest.

I would like to get the year in front. Is that possible using `toLocalString`?  I tried to change "en-US" to "iso" or "en-GB" but neither one will put the year in front.

Comment: You can use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) API to extract the various numbers from the Date instance and assemble them however you like, and adjust as necessary based on what `.getTimezoneOffset()` tells you about the actual local timezone.

Comment: `getTimezoneOffset` is not useful. my server is running utc, so local time is irrelevant. What I want is to format the date string in Chicago time with the year in front.  There does not seem to be any way to do that except (1) call `toLocalString` as above, and (2) parse the result string and reorder the substrings!  Surely there is a better way?

Comment: Well if you're doing it server-side and you know your server's time setting then yes of course. However overall getting the "pieces" of a date (day, month, year, hour, minute, seconds, etc) is *really* easy via the Date API.

Comment: let now = new Date(); let res = `${now.getFullYear()}-${now.getMonth()+1}-${now.getDate()} ${now.getHours()}:${now.getMinutes()}:${now.getSeconds()}`

Comment: @Pointy Are the "pieces" in Chicago time or UTC?  I need the pieces to be in Chicago time.

Comment: @MichaelHobbs the `getHours` is returning the wrong value. It always return local time but i need it to return Chicago time.

Comment: @JohnHenckel without a lib like Moment.js you will have to deal with DST on your own. let now = new Date(); let tz = -6 // or -5 let res = ${now.getFullYear()}-${now.getMonth()+1}-${now.getDate()} ${now.getHours() - tz}:${now.getMinutes()}:${now.getSeconds()} Maybe as Pointy suggest you can use .getTimezoneOffset(). I generally turn to Moment for any date/time issues as it can get ugly very quickly.

Comment: The pieces of the date are in local time, so you should pre-adjust your UST date by the timezone offset you want (for Chicago time, 6 hours or 5 hours depending on whether you want DST).